# How to quickly scroll to top of long list in iOS?

Tags: mail.app, ui, macos, ios

I've recently hooked my MS Exchange account into Mail.app in iOS, and consequently, the list of email in my inbox is extremely long. iOS has the unfortunate habit of scrolling the mail list to the middle of the list whenever I rotate the iPad, and it takes me a very long time to scroll back up.

I'm wondering if there's a way to quickly scroll back up to the top of the very long inbox list in iOS Mail.app, so that I can see my unread messages?

Answer (score 9):

**Tap** the Status Bar at the top of the screen.

> In Safari, Mail, Contacts, and many other apps, tap the status bar at
>   the top of the screen — which displays the network information, time,
>   and battery level — to scroll quickly to the top.
>
> *Source: http://www.apple.com/iphone/tips/*

Answer (score -2):

option and the up arrow.  If you are using outlook on a mac, this is the fastest way to get to the top.  I hope that helps because I had the same problem.

Comment: How do you press Option-Up on an iOS device?

Comment: iOS, the system in the question, is for portable devices such as iPhone and iPad.